# MIPS I instruction immediate field

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-code, immediate-operand

The field is used by arithmetic and conditional branch instructions.

First question is:

What would be the range of values which can be stored in an immediate arithmetic instruction and conditional branch?

Second is:

if a MIPS processor has 64 registers, how would you change the immediate instruction format to reference these registers? How would I draw and label the format?

Comment: Soo... what are your thoughts? Tell us what you are thinking and maybe we can point out where your going astray

Comment: Not sure don't really know where to start with this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Part 1**:

As illustrated by this diagram:

[image: MIPS instruction formats]

The I-Type instruction has 16 bits reserved for the immediate field. This of course means that the immediate field can take on 2<sup>16</sup> possible values. If we consider that the immediate field can be positive or negative (1 bit is used for the sign) we can see that the max would be 2<sup>15</sup> - 1 and the min would be −(2<sup>15</sup> - 1).

`andi`, `ori`, and `xori` zero-extend the immediate (0 to 2<sup>16</sup> - 1), while all other MIPS I-type instructions sign-extend the immediate/offset.

---

**Part 2:**

Again, looking at the diagram above we can see that the rs and rt registers are specified with 5 bits. This is because there are 32 registers in the mips instruction set — i.e. 2<sup>5</sup>. If there were instead 64 registers, both the rs and rt fields would need to be 6 bits long, thus leaving only 14 bits for the immediate field.

Comment: thanks! for part 2 if both rs and rt are now 6 and imm is 14 does that change op? if not the total would just be 32                              edit: ahh ok I get it 2^6 in registers thanks a lot