# MIPS - SPIM parser immediate value out of range for bitwise ANDI

Tags: assembly, mips, spim, immediate-operand

Was trying to test my program with SPIM and have this message

spim: (parser) immediate value (-16) out of range (0 .. 65535) on line 56 of file code1.a

```
  andi $t1, $t0, 0xfffffff0
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIPS processor cannot do that operation in one instruction.  The `andi` instruction is an I-Type instruction, which holds a 16-bit immediate — further the `andi` instruction zero extends the 16-bit immediate to 32-bit, so it cannot hold a negative number (`ori` & `xori` also zero extend, whereas `addi` and all the others sign extend the immediate).

Whenever we cannot do something in one instruction, use a sequence of instructions.  In this case, load the immediate into a register, then use the `and` R-Type instruction.

FYI, the MARS simulator's assembler will take the `andi $t1, $t0, 0xfffffff0`, though it treats that as a pseudo instruction and will expand that one line of assembly into a 3-instruction machine code sequence that loads the constant into a register (using two instructions: one more than needed to do the job), then uses that `and`.

Apparently, Spim doesn't offer that particular pseudo instruction.

Comment: The bitwise operations all zero-extend, also including `xori` (in addition to `ori` and `andi` that you mentioned).  But yes, all others sign-extend.  (https://doc.lagout.org/electronics/doc/mips/See%20mips%20run.pdf#page=249).  And yes, MARS's handling of "extended" pseudo-instructions is sub-optimal, not using a single `addiu` to generate `-16` in a register.

Comment: In this case, I guess `srl $t1, $t0, 4 ; sll $t1, $t1, 4` would be preferable.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Only if you have no spare register for an in-place operation.  Otherwise `addiu $t1, $zero, -16` / `and $t1, $t1, $t0` would be at least as cheap and have better ILP / shorter critical path for superscalar / OoO exec.  Only the bitwise ops zero-extend; `addi` or `addiu` can materialize small negative constants in one instruction.  (I looked for duplicates for this question; [MIPS I instruction immediate field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23123106) was the closest I found, after editing it to mention that not all instructions sign-extend.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, was looking at the official Berkeley MIPS green sheet, to verify when I wrote that, only to now notice that it doesn't provide RTL for `xori`, so I missed that one.

Comment: I'm not aware of any good MIPS quick-reference instruction list :(  They all seem to be missing some true machine instructions, like `nor`, `bgezal`, or `bgtz`.